# Video.js vidSwap Flash fallback

Tags: javascript, flash, video, video.js

I have an intro video initially loading within a video tag and then replace that with other videos using the vidSwap function. For some reason the code below just reloads the intro video. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<div style="width:944px; height:402px; margin-left:8px; margin-top:8px">
    <div style="width:223px; height:402px; float:left;">

        <div id="menu" style="height:400px;">
            <a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap('video/video-1.mp4'); return false;">
                <div class="button">Button 1</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap('video/video-2.mp4'); return false;">
                <div class="button">Button 2</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap('video/video-3.mp4'); return false;">
                <div class="button">Button 3</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="video-panel" style="width:711px; height:400px; float:left; margin-left:10px; position:relative; background-color:#000">

        <section>
            <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="711" height="400">
                <source src="video/intro.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>

            <script>
                var myPlayer = _V_("video");

                function vidSwap(vidURL) {
                    myPlayer.src = vidURL;
                    myPlayer.load();
                    myPlayer.play();
                }
            </script>

        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi... can anybody help with this? Please?

Comment: try using myPlayer.src( vidURL );